# Consulta ajax al inciar la pagina

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una consulta ajax al iniciar la la página.
No se el motivo pero no me muestra nada y el div me queda con el texto inicial, el cual se debería reemplazar automaticamente al traer la consutla
Mi codigo es el siguiente

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $.ajax({
          url: 'consultas.php',
          success: function(r) {
          $('#destino').html(r);
            }
           });
          });
 </script>
```

y el archivo php (consultas.php), puse a modo de que devuelva algo, para no cargar toda la consulta a la base de datos en la prueba el siguiente texto

```
<?php
$data = "Soy la consulta";
echo $data;
?>
```

En el archivo a mostrar esta el div con su nombre correcto

```
<div id="destino"> Mostrando el resultado </div>
```

Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal ?

Nota: En la consola me da un error en la linea

> $(document).ready(function() {

"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

SOLUCIONADO:
EL problema era que estaba llamando al jquery.min.js despues de hacer la consulta ajax. Lo pose por arriba y listo
Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: El error que te aparece es porque no está encontrando la librería de jQuery. La incluiste en el head? O al final del body, pero ANTES de tu código JS.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código JS está buscando un elemento una *clase* llamada "destino":

```
$('.destino')
```

En tu código HTML tenés un elemento con un *id* llamado destino, no una clase:

```
<div id="destino">...</div>
```

O cambiás tu JS:

```
$('#destino')
```

O cambiás tu HTML:

```
<div class="destino">...</div>
```

Comment: ahí edite la consulta. Es verdad que estaba mal esa parte, de igual modo lo he puesto  como id (#) pero sigue sin funcionar no entiendo el motivo 
Hay algo más que esté mal en el código ?

Gracias por responder

Comment: Ojo que lo dejaste como `$('.#destino')`, sacale el punto. Si ese no es el problema, fijate por favor con la ventana de desarrollador abierta que aparece en la solapa red/network. Debería intentar cargar el archivo "consultas.php". Pero al no estar usando una URL absoluta, puede que no esté llegando al destino adecuado. Fijate y publicá una captura o comentanos que aparece.

Comment: Ahí modifique eso también, ejej es que ya tengo los ojos cruzados.
Sigue sin funcionar. He editado la consulta y puse el error de consola que me da 

El archivo consulta.php esta en el raiz al igual que el otro archivo. Si hago un include("consulta.php"); me me lo muestra bien por lo que el archivo es accesible desde esa url
La verdad que no se que puede ser :-(